# UDP server consumes all processor time in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, select, udp

I'm developing a client/server application. Client and server run on two different machines running Ubuntu 16.04. The client sends two variables that influence the flow of the server part, therefore, I want to decrease packet loss rate as much as possible. My application is thread-based.

In one thread UDP server is running. My project has a GUI implemented using Qt. When I tried to implement UDP server to be blocking, the whole program and the GUI froze until a packet is received. And sometimes even when a packet is received the program didn't response.

Therefore, I thought non-blocking UDP is the best way to do it. I managed to make UDP non-blocking using [select()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select). Now comes the problem. If I set the timeout of `recvfrom` to be 10ms and the thread is allowed to run every 10ms, almost no packet is lost but, apparently, the UDP thread consumes all the processor time that the program freezes. If I increased the interval of calling the thread or reduced the timeout interval, around 80% of the packets are lost. I know that UDP is connectionless protocol and TCP may be a better option, but I have to use `UDP` as the client side sends the packets over UDP.

The question is: how can I reduce the packet loss rate without blocking the other threads from executing efficiently?

Following is my code (the based on a Stackoverflow answer which, at the moment, I can't find to refer here).

```
void receiveUDP(void)
{
    fd_set readfds;
    static int fd;
    static struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 10000;
    static char buffer[10];
    static int length;

    if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket failed");
        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    memset( &serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr) );
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons( 50037 );    
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );     
    if( bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        return;
    }

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &readfds);

    int rv = select(fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if(rv == -1)
    {
        printf("Error in Select\n");
        _exit(0);
    }
    else if(rv == 0)
    {
        printf("Timeout\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(fd, &readfds))
        {
            length = recvfrom(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0, NULL, 0);

            if(length < 0)
            {
                perror("recvfrom failed");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d bytes received: \n", length);
            }
        }
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: 1. Why use non-blocking mode? You're doubling your system calls that way. Just loop blocking in `recvfrom()`. 2. You're wasting a lot of time printing each character of every datagram. Try just printing the length.

Comment: @EJP thanks for your quick response. I've updated my answer after trying commenting out printing the contents of the received packet.

Comment: But you haven't tried it in blocking mode. And you started out by saying it consumes 100% processor time, but now you're saying it blocks the GUI, which isnt' the same thing at all. Which is it? and if the latter, why are you executing network operations on the GUI thread?

Comment: @EJP. Thank you so much EJP for your hints, they were very helpful. It was my fault. I thought that when the GUI froze, the UDP connection was blocking the other threads from executing. After reading your last comment, I rechecked my code and found that UDP was really running on the GUI thread. After running it on a separate thread every thing worked fine. I still don't understand, if the UDP thread is called each 10ms and it has a timeout of 10 ms then it will consume all the processor time, right? Even when I tried UDP in blocking mode in a separate thread, it worked fine.

Comment: No, it will block for up to 10ms, which doesn't consume any processor time at all.

Comment: After this 10ms of blocking ends, the thread will allowed to run again, as it's called each 10ms, then it will block for up to 10ms and so on. Therefore, whenever it finishes, it will start again, as far as I understand, right?

Comment: Well of course, if the `select()` is inside a loop, but yours isn't.